# How do I make a security code column that resets after a certain amount of time in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, swift, ios8

I am building an iOS application with a RoR backend. One of my models needs to be looked up by a "4-character code". The permitted characters are A-Z (uppercase only) and 0-9. I want to assign a code to the model in the create action of my controller. The generated code cannot be the same as the code for another object created within the past 36 hours. I want to minimize the lookup time so the function runs quickly. The output of the create action is to render the object, with the new security code, in JSON.

here is my code so far:

```
def create
    my_model = MyModel.new(my_model_params)

    my_model.security_code = ## create 4 character security code here...

    if my_model.save
        render :json => my_model, :status => 200
        return
    else
        render :json => my_model.errors, :status => 422
    end
end
```

Comment: As mentioned in comments on the answer I've now deleted, this is just not a good implementation because of the possibility of a code being issued to person A, then removed by the sweeper, then a new code is created for person B that happens to be the same code, and then person A (unaware of their code being removed) uses it and gets whatever goodies were meant for person B.